# Rpi zero2 w KVM

Tags: remote, hid

I would like to use the pi as kvm. I want to send keyboard/mouse signals from one pc to the other one and record video using a usb video in card. I have read about g_hid and libcomposite but im not sure if thats the way to go.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a how to here
https://randomnerdtutorials.com/raspberry-pi-zero-usb-keyboard-hid/
But what i want to do is to write into a ssh terminal connected to the device and send the input to the emulated keyboard. How can i modify the python script to read the input and escape with combination?